# Why is Domino log Agent Manager: Agent printing: Event ID = 64

Tags: lotus-domino, agents

I was reviewing my log.nsf and note that this alert is being generated at a rate of 10-20 times per second. I have no debug parameters set in the ini file and this is not a 'print' I'd use in my agents. It doesn't appear to harm anything but I can find nothing that helps me understand where the alert comes from or how to make it go away.
Thanks for any tips on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify what agent(s) is(are) running while this message is appearing. It has to be one of the agents. It may not be something in your agent code, but it has to be something an agent that is running. If it's not directly in the code, it's in something that the code is calling.